# variable in while loop retains only last value and inserts last value in temporary table

Tags: mysql

If I test my following procedure, then for all rows with value of status variable that we got in last select exists statement. Status variable retain only its last values not intermediate values. what is wrong with my procedure. I am not able to figure out.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS check_userfollowed_by_fbuser;
DELIMITER $
create procedure check_userfollowed_by_fbuser (
                 IN myArrayOfValue TEXT, 
                 IN leaderID       INT(11)
                 )
BEGIN

DECLARE status TINYINT(1);
DECLARE value VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE pos INT(11);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE fbid_exists_result (fbid varchar(255), status tinyint(1))      
 ENGINE=MEMORY;
 WHILE (CHAR_LENGTH(myArrayOfValue) > 0)
 DO
  SET pos=LOCATE(  ',', myArrayOfValue);

  IF pos>0 THEN
  SET value = LEFT(  myArrayOfValue,pos-1 );
  SET myArrayOfValue= SUBSTRING( myArrayOfValue,pos+1);                                                                                
  ELSE
  SET value = myArrayOfValue;
  SET myArrayOfValue='';
  END IF;

  SELECT EXISTS (
                 SELECT 1 
                   FROM users_followings 
                        LEFT JOIN users 
                                  ON users_followings.userID=users.userID 
                  WHERE FacebookID=value 
                    AND LeaderUserID=leaderID 
                  LIMIT 1
                ) 
    INTO status;
  INSERT INTO fbid_exists_result VALUES(value,status); 

END WHILE;
SELECT fbid,
       status 
  FROM fbid_exists_result ; 
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS fbid_exists_result ;       

END$
```

Comment: Since you're using a `LEFT JOIN`, a row will always be returned if it exists in `users_followings`, so `EXISTS` will always be true. If you want to test whether there are matching rows, use `INNER JOIN`.